# Kinematic constraints and model of a tricycle

Tags: kinematics

I am trying to solve an exercise which deals with the kinematic constraints and model of a tricycle, but I can't get the right answer.

A front wheel driven tricycle has two rear wheels (1 and 2) which can move freely and a steered front wheel (3), and the wheels' parameters are:
\begin{align*}
   \beta_1 &= 0 \\
   \beta_2 &= \pi \\
   \beta_3 &= \rho(t) + \pi/2
  \end{align*}
where $\beta_i$ is the angle between the $i$-wheel's wheel plane and the chassis and $\rho$ is the angle between the front wheel and the robot's x-axis.
The tricycle is in the configuration shown below.

[image: tricycle]

Find the odometry equations for the tricycle, knowing that the input is the movement of the front wheel in one sample $\mathrm{d}l$ and the steering angle $\rho$, while the output is the pose of the tricycle in world coordinates.

To begin with, I started with writing the rolling and sliding constraints for each wheel, and to do so I defined $\alpha_i$ to be the angle between the segment which connects the origo to wheel $i$ and the x-axis, $r_i$ to be the radius of wheel $i$, and $\dot{\varphi_i}$ to be the angular velocity of the wheel $i$. Moreover, I assumed the rotation matrix $R(\theta)$ and the vector of linear velocities $\dot{\xi_I}$ to be defined as:
\begin{align*}
   R(\theta) &= 
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
    -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
   \end{bmatrix} \\
   \dot{\xi_I} &= \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{x} \\
    \dot{y} \\
    \dot{\theta}
   \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align*}

With regards to the left wheel (wheel one), the rolling and sliding constraints are given by the relationships:
\begin{align}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \sin(\alpha_1 + \beta_1) & -\cos(\alpha_1 + \beta_1) & -w/2 \cos(\beta_1)
   \end{bmatrix}
   R(\theta) \dot{\xi_I} - r_1 \dot{\varphi_1} &= 0 \\
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha_1 + \beta_1) & \sin(\alpha_1 + \beta_1) & w/2 \sin(\beta_1)
   \end{bmatrix}
   R(\theta) \dot{\xi_I} &= 0 \label{eq:sliding1}
  \end{align}

With regards to the right wheel (wheel two), the rolling and sliding constraints are given by the relationships:
\begin{align}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \sin(\alpha_2 + \beta_2) & -\cos(\alpha_2 + \beta_2) & -w/2 \cos(\beta_2)
   \end{bmatrix}
   R(\theta) \dot{\xi_I} - r_2 \dot{\varphi_2} &= 0 \\
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha_2 + \beta_2) & \sin(\alpha_2 + \beta_2) & w/2 \sin(\beta_2)
   \end{bmatrix}
   R(\theta) \dot{\xi_I} &= 0
  \end{align}

With regards to the front wheel (wheel three), the rolling and sliding constraints are given by the relationships:
\begin{align}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \sin(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & -\cos(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & -L \cos(\beta_3)
   \end{bmatrix}
   R(\theta) \dot{\xi_I} - r_3 \dot{\varphi_3} &= 0 \label{eq:rolling3}\\
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & \sin(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & L \sin(\beta_3)
   \end{bmatrix}
   R(\theta) \dot{\xi_I} &= 0 \label{eq:sliding3}
  \end{align}

Since the rear wheels are parallel and actually free to roll, out of their four constraints, only one sliding constraint needs to be kept into consideration. More precisely, it is possible to get the kinematic model of the robot by writing the left wheel's sliding contraint (for example) and the front wheel's constraints in matrix form, as shown below:
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha_1 + \beta_1) & \sin(\alpha_1 + \beta_1) & \frac{w}{2} \sin(\beta_1) \\
    \sin(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & -\cos(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & -L \cos(\beta_3) \\
    \cos(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & \sin(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & L \sin(\beta_3)
   \end{bmatrix}
   R(\theta) \dot{\xi}_I = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    r_3\dot{\varphi}_3 \\
    0
   \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}
Solving for $\dot{\xi}_I$, it is:
\begin{equation}
   \dot{\xi}_I = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\
    -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\alpha_1 + \beta_1) & \sin(\alpha_1 + \beta_1) & \frac{w}{2} \sin(\beta_1) \\
    \sin(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & -\cos(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & -L \cos(\beta_3) \\
    \cos(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & \sin(\alpha_3 + \beta_3) & L \sin(\beta_3)
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    r_3\dot{\varphi}_3 \\
    0
   \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}
Since $\alpha_1 = \pi/2$, $\alpha_2 = -\pi/2$, $\alpha_3 = 0$, $\beta_1 = 0$, $\beta_2 = \pi$, $\beta_3 = \rho + \pi/2$, the last equation becomes (temporarily omitting the time dependency of $\theta(t)$ and $\rho(t)$ for the sake of brevity):
\begin{align*}
   \dot{\xi}_I &= 
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\
    -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\pi/2) & \sin(\pi/2) & \frac{w}{2} \sin(0) \\
    \sin(\rho + \pi/2) & -\cos(\rho + \pi/2) & -L \cos(\rho + \pi/2) \\
    \cos(\rho + \pi/2) & \sin(\rho + \pi/2) & L \sin(\rho + \pi/2)
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    r_3\dot{\varphi}_3 \\
    0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \\
   &=
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\
    -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \cos(\rho) & \sin(\rho) & L\sin(\rho) \\
    -\sin(\rho) & \cos(\rho) & L\cos(\rho)
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    r_3\dot{\varphi}_3 \\
    0
   \end{bmatrix} \\
   &=
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
    \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \cos(\rho) & -\sin(\rho) \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    -1/L & \sin(\rho)/L & \cos(\rho)/L
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    r_3\dot{\varphi}_3 \\
    0
   \end{bmatrix} = \\
   &= r_3\dot{\varphi}_3
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\rho)\cos(\theta) \\
    \cos(\rho)\sin(\theta) \\
    \sin(\rho)/L
   \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align*}

Therefore, the odometry equations for the tricycle at the instant $t+1$ are given by:
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    x(t+1) \\
    y(t+1) \\
    \theta(t+1)
   \end{bmatrix} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
    x(t) \\
    y(t) \\
    \theta(t)
   \end{bmatrix} + \dot{\xi}_I(t) t
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
    x(t) \\
    y(t) \\
    \theta(t)
   \end{bmatrix}
   +
   \mathrm{d}l
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\rho(t))\cos(\theta(t)) \\
    \cos(\rho(t))\sin(\theta(t)) \\
    \sin(\rho(t))/L
   \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}

My answer, however, is different from the correct one, which should be:
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    x(t+1) \\
    y(t+1) \\
    \theta(t+1)
   \end{bmatrix} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
    x(t) \\
    y(t) \\
    \theta(t)
   \end{bmatrix}
   +
   \mathrm{d}l
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\rho(t))\sin(\theta(t)) \\
    \cos(\rho(t))\cos(\theta(t)) \\
    \sin(\rho(t))/L
   \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}
I can't understand what I am doing wrong, so I would appreciate if somebody could point out my mistakes.